# ModuleNotFoundError: "projectname" DJANGO + UWSGI + NGINX (UBUNTU 20.04)

Tags: python, django, nginx, wsgi

I want to deploy my django project but uwsgi gives me an error:

```
 File "/root/eva/lawyer/lawyer/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/root/eva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 1>
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "/root/eva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19>
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/root/eva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", li>
    self._setup(name)
  File "/root/eva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", li>
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/root/eva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", li>
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ' lawyer'
```

my project is called a lawyer. it has a standard structure. The configuration files and wsgi are located in the folder of the same name - lawyer. lawyer/lawyer/settings.py, lawyer/lawyer/wsgi.py

"lawyer" is not a python module, but the name of the project and the project directory where I store the settings and the wsgi file

Please help me to run my project

my uwsgi ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /root/eva/lawyer
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= lawyer.settings
wsgi-file = /root/eva/lawyer/lawyer/wsgi.py
#module = lawyer.uwsgi:application
workers = 1
max-requests = 5000
#plugins-dir=/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/
plugins = python3
#virtualenv = /root/eva/venv
pythonpath = /root/eva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
processes = 5
threads = 2
master = true
die-on-term = true
socket = /run/uwsgi/app/myapp/socket
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
uid = user
gui = user
```

My project structure:

```
lawyer/
  ...
  manage.py
  lawyer/
    ...
    settings.py
    wsgi.py  
  someapp/
    ...
```

Comment: you can't have a folder name with a `.` (`lawyer.laywer`). it is looking for a module

Comment: I do not understand what you're talking about. I don't have a folder with a dot in the name. The project is called "lawyer" and it contains the "lawyer" directory with settings and wsgi python files. This is a standard django project structure. Django forms it himself in this way

Comment: can you share your settings.py? more specifically- installed_apps section

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
]